# how to update listview with data from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

how to update listview with a particular column from the database table?
i used the below code

```
   String con = "datasource = localhost; port=3306;username=root;password=****";
        MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(con);

        string qw = "select wine from cms.menulist";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(qw, mycon);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt1);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {
            string wine = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
            listView1.Items.Add(wine);
        }
```

but this code generates a list view with two columns .the data from the mysql is placed in these two columns i want the list view to contain only 1 column

Comment: You should not post your passwords here, even if that service runs on your localhost. By the way, what is your problem here? As far as I can see, you are querying your database and receiving one particular column called `wine`. I don't see any other column. Maybe the listview just breaks up into a new column if the amount of data is too high?

Comment: yes the listview breaks into 2 columns.no the amount of data is not high its less than 50 values

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `ListView` is constructing their columns based on the width of the items inserted. This behavior is probably causing your problem so you have some options / workarounds to get started with:

1. Size your `ListView` correctly in order to fit just one column. That is possible if you know how wide your data is.
2. Add a column to your `ListView` and set it's width according to the total width of the `ListView` minus 4 (for the column). After that, set the column style to `ColumnHeaderStyle.None` and set the `View` to `View.Details`

   ```
   listView1.View = View.Details;
   listView1.Columns.Add("somecolumn");
   listView1.Columns[0].Width = listView1.Width - 4;
   listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
   ```
3. Stop using `ListView` and think about some alternatives such as `ListBox` and `DataGridView`

Comment: thanks the  option 2 worked .. is there anyway using which i can autosize the listview according to the data it load. because currently its just showing a few rows and i have to scroll down to view the rest. is there anyway i can view all the data without scrolling

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421588/listview-auto-size-to-show-all-items

Comment: hmmm it says its tricky to do this. is there an alternate way to display a column from the database table on the form. i don't want to use datagridview as i do not like the look of it. i want the data to be show in a simple tabular format containing only 1 column

Comment: I'm only aware of the `DataGridView` since that is usually the way to go for that. You may do some research about that. If you care about the look, consider WPF as framework for your application.

Comment: i initially didn't like the datagridview due to the gray space on the left hand side. just researched and found out a way to remove the grey area. now can i view all the data retrieved in the datagridview without using the scroll bar. because currently i can only view a few of the rows . is there a way in which the datagridview can resize it self to display all the rows?